# Distance Calculator Lat and Long

Tags: javascript, formula, distance

I have a form which I want to allow users to manually put lat and long coordinates in to see the distance between points.  How can I bind the input fields to my javascript when the submit button is pressed?

My code

```js
var Rm = 3961;
var Rk = 6373;
                
function findDistance(frm) {                    
 var t1, n1, t2, n2, lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, dlat, dlon, a, c, dm, dk, mi, km;
                
                // get values for lat1, lon1, lat2, and lon2
                //t1 = frm.lat1.value;
                //n1 = frm.lon1.value;
                //t2 = frm.lat2.value;
                //n2 = frm.lon2.value;
                t1 = document.getElementById('lat1').value;
                n1 = document.getElementById('lon1').value;
                t2 = document.getElementById('lat2').value;
                n2 = document.getElementById('lon2').value;
          
                
                // convert coordinates to radians
                lat1 = deg2rad(t1);
                lon1 = deg2rad(n1);
                lat2 = deg2rad(t2);
                lon2 = deg2rad(n2);
                
                // find the differences between the coordinates
                dlat = lat2 - lat1;
                dlon = lon2 - lon1;
                
                // here's the heavy lifting
                a  = Math.pow(Math.sin(dlat/2),2) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.pow(Math.sin(dlon/2),2);
                c  = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a),Math.sqrt(1-a)); // great circle distance in radians
                dm = c * Rm; // great circle distance in miles
                dk = c * Rk; // great circle distance in km
                
                // round the results down to the nearest 1/1000
                mi = round(dm);
                km = round(dk);
                
                // display the result
                frm.mi.value = mi;
                frm.km.value = km;                    
                console.log(mi + 'miles');
                console.log(km + 'km');
                $('#calculated').html(mi + 'miles');
}


// convert degrees to radians
function deg2rad(deg) {
                rad = deg * Math.PI/180; // radians = degrees * pi/180
                return rad;
}


// round to the nearest 1/1000
function round(x) {
                return Math.round( x * 1000) / 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm">
  <input type="text" id="lat1" name="lat1"  />
  <input type="text" id="lon1" name="lon1" />                
  <input type="text" id="lat2" name="lat2" />
  <input type="text" id="lon2" name="lon2" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="findDistance()" />
</form>
<div id="calculated">Results...</div>
```

Comment: You seem to already have everything you need. What is not working?

Comment: the problem is probably the submit button causing the page to reload because of the behaviour of a submit button in a form ... if you don't want to submit something to a server, don't use a form or type='submit' input - problem solved

Comment: These two lines `frm.mi.value = mi;` and the next cause an error. If you comment them out and heed the advice by @JaromandaX your script works.

Comment: because `frm` is undefined - rather than a parameter of the function, you should `var frm = document.getElementById('frm');` at the top of the main function ... then that will work **if** you add some (read only) inputs with name `mi` and `km` ... or just remove the `frm.??` lines altogether

Comment: Ahhh damn, right enough.  I used submit instead of a button.  Thanks guys, works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to this (add `return`):

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="return findDistance()" />
```

Then, in your `findDistance()` function, return `false` at the bottom line. This will prevent the form from actually submitting

You could also strip away the `<form>` and `</form>` tag. Or change the button to not be a type `submit`

Answer (score 0):

```
$form=document.getElementById('frm');

$form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    findDistance();
});
```

There's various different methods but this method would allow you to get the children of the form and send them to your `findDistance()` function. This means you could have more than one form on the page.
you could also include coverage for older browsers like:

```
if($form.addEventListener){
    $form.addEventListener('submit',function('some object you\'re sending')});
}else{
    $form.attachEvent('onSubmit',findDistance('some object you\'re sending'));
}
```

Also don't forget to pass your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you change type="submit" to type="button", your problem is almost solved.

I see you use jQuery only on 1 line; I replaced that line with non-jQuery javascript.  Feel free to use jQuery anyway.

This works:

```
<form id="frm">
  <input type="text" id="lat1" name="lat1" value="50.84684892257945"/>
  <input type="text" id="lon1" name="lon1" value="4.3524657636880715"/>                
  <input type="text" id="lat2" name="lat2" value="48.86109400096986"/>
  <input type="text" id="lon2" name="lon2" value="2.3359246999025185"/> 
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="findDistance()" />
</form>
<div id="calculated">Results...</div>
<script>
var Rm = 3961;
var Rk = 6373;

function findDistance(frm) {
  var t1, n1, t2, n2, lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, dlat, dlon, a, c, dm, dk, mi, km;

  t1 = document.getElementById('lat1').value;
  n1 = document.getElementById('lon1').value;
  t2 = document.getElementById('lat2').value;
  n2 = document.getElementById('lon2').value;

  // convert coordinates to radians
  lat1 = deg2rad(t1);
  lon1 = deg2rad(n1);
  lat2 = deg2rad(t2);
  lon2 = deg2rad(n2);

  // find the differences between the coordinates
  dlat = lat2 - lat1;
  dlon = lon2 - lon1;

  // here's the heavy lifting
  a  = Math.pow(Math.sin(dlat/2),2) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.pow(Math.sin(dlon/2),2);
  c  = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a),Math.sqrt(1-a)); // great circle distance in radians
  dm = c * Rm; // great circle distance in miles
  dk = c * Rk; // great circle distance in km

  // round the results down to the nearest 1/1000
  mi = round(dm);
  km = round(dk);

  console.log(mi + 'miles');
  console.log(km + 'km');
  //$('#calculated').html(mi + 'miles');
  document.getElementById('calculated').innerHTML = mi + ' miles';
}

// convert degrees to radians
function deg2rad(deg) {
  rad = deg * Math.PI/180; // radians = degrees * pi/180
  return rad;
}

// round to the nearest 1/1000
function round(x) {
  return Math.round( x * 1000) / 1000;
}
</script>
```